# javascript validate form check - echo out errors in form?

Tags: javascript, validation

i have currently got a javascript code which validates my form and shows an error if a field is not completed. i also want to know how i could echo out the errors in the form so for instance if 'fname' is not filled in then this says 'You did not fill in fname' or if 'fname' and fcompany' are not filled in this says

```
You did not fill in fname 
you did not fill in fcompany
```

Heres my html:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Company Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Company Registration Number: <input type="text" name="fcompany">
```

heres my javascript:

```
<script>
function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["myForm"]["cname"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
   {
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
   document.getElementById("alertBox").style.display='block';
   return false;
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("alertBox").innerHTML = "Your error here"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have your validate function build an array of errors, then have another function take the errors array and build the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/J9LJj/

```
function displayErrors(errors){
    var container = document.getElementById("alertBox");
    var html = "<ul>";

    for(var i=0; i<errors.length; i++){
        html += "<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";

    container.innerHTML = html;
    container.style.display = "block";
}

function validateForm(){
    var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var fcompany= document.forms["myForm"]["fcompany"].value;

    var errors = [];

    if(fname == ""){
        errors.push("you did not fill in fname");
    }
    if(fcompany == ""){
        errors.push("you did not fill in fcompany");
    }

    if(errors.length > 0){
        displayErrors(errors);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for this but its not working, its not cancelling the default action of the form and the form is submitting to the next page, without showing any errors. i want to disbale the default form action and display the errors on the parent page

Comment: This is working, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J9LJj/ if it's not working for you, check the field names `fname` and `cname` are correct for your actual form. Also look at the error console (F12) which should narrow the problem down.